# How did they make the shimmering colours when Mork calls Orson?

Tags: film-techniques, effects, mork-and-mindy

At the end of every episode of *Mork & Mindy*, the alien visitor Mork calls his boss Orson to give a report.  The show depicts the call by having Mork chant, "Mork calling Orson.  Come in, Orson!" as the camera zooms in on his face.  Soon this shot dissolves into a bundle of vivid colours which shimmers and undulates.  The object is semi-transparent, making it appear three-dimensional.

The following animated GIF, produced from [this YouTube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UY5lsZZ6iw), gives some idea of the effect, though neither of these match the quality of the DVD:

[image: An animation showing Mork chanting, "Mork calling Orson. Come in, Orson!" as the camera zooms in on his face. Soon this shot dissolves into a bundle of vivid colours which shimmers and undulates. The object is semi-transparent, making it appears three-dimensional.]

Given that the show premiered in 1978, I assume that this effect was produced with analogue equipment.  How exactly was it done (or if nobody knows for sure, how *might* it have been done)?

Comment: Better quality YouTube clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdOxzI6YNwE

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The special effects were created by a company called [Laserium](http://www.famousfix.com/topic/mork-and-mindy/crew)'. Simply put, the "hologram" you see when Mork communicates with Orson is simply a series of "dyed" (e.g. colour-filtered) lasers, passed through a rippled piece of glass and projected directly into the camera lens.

> *"One last secret we'll give away is how we produce the beautiful clouds
>   and aurorae. This is actually our simplest effect. All we do is shine
>   the laser through rippled plastic or glass like you might find on a
>   shower door or a bathroom window. Move the plastic slowly in front of
>   the beam, and the cloud comes alive"* - <sub><sup>http://www.laserium.com/Inside.html</sup></sub>

[image]